# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_18_input to have shape (128,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification

I change the tensorflow version from latest to 2.0.1 and now the error is above : Could anybody help me ?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

Categories = ["Badshahi Masjid", "Minare Pakistan", "ShahiQila(Lahore Fort)"]

sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

print(tf.__version__)

def prepare(filepath):
    IMG_SIZE = (124, 124)
    img_array = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, IMG_SIZE)
    keyImage, desImage = sift.detectAndCompute(new_array, None)
    feat = np.sum(desImage, axis=0)
    return feat


model = tf.keras.models.load_model("SuperClassPredictions.h5")
prediction = model.predict([prepare('E:\Python Telusko\OpenCv\download.jpg')])
print(prediction)
print(Categories[int(prediction[0][0])])
```

Comment: Try removing square parenthesis around prepare function call.

Comment: I tried this one before but all in vain . We have to pass a list here if there is single image either or multiples

Comment: What is size of feat returned by the function?

Comment: I print feat.shape and it is giving me value (128,)

Comment: I resolved it by using feat.reshape(-1,128) because this is the shape that tensorflow bis expecting